# Lua Dump in C++

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, lua, dump

I want to export a binary Chunk with lua_dump or luaU_dump..

The error: the return is only <-LuaR

Don't have a compile error or static problems with the code, only the <-LuaR return

What can i do? to result the problem?

```
private:
const char* buildLua(QString luaScript)
{
    const Proto* f;
    char *byteCode = 0L;
    size_t byteCodeLen = 0;
    wdata wd = { &byteCodeLen, &byteCode };
    string ts = luaScript.toStdString();
    const char* cs;
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    f=combine(L,0);
    luaL_loadstring(L,ts.c_str());
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_lock(L);
    luaU_dump(L,f,kpt_lua_Writer,&wd,1);
    lua_unlock(L);
    lua_close(L);
    cs = byteCode;
    return cs;
}

static const char* kpt_lua_Reader(lua_State *L, void *ud, size_t *size)
{
    UNUSED(L);
    if ((*(int*)ud)--)
    {
        *size=sizeof(FUNCTION)-1;
        return FUNCTION;
    }
    else
    {
        *size=0;
        return NULL;
    }
}

static int kpt_lua_Writer(lua_State * /*l*/, const void *p, size_t sz, void *ud)
{
    wdata *wd = (wdata *)ud;

    char *newData;

    if((newData = (char *)realloc(*(wd->data), (*(wd->len)) + sz))) {
        memcpy(newData + (*(wd->len)), p, sz);
        *(wd->data) = newData;
        *(wd->len) += sz;
    } else {
        free(newData);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static const Proto* combine(lua_State* L, int n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return toproto(L,-1);
    else
    {
        Proto* f;
        int i=n;
        if (lua_load(L,kpt_lua_Reader,&i,"=(keppedev)",NULL)!=LUA_OK) fatal(lua_tostring(L,-1));
        f=toproto(L,-1);
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            f->p[i]=toproto(L,i-n-1);
            if (f->p[i]->sizeupvalues>0) f->p[i]->upvalues[0].instack=0;
        }
        f->sizelineinfo=0;
        return f;
    }
}

static void fatal(const char* message)
{
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
    QMessageBox::warning(widget,"Keppe Develop",message);
}
```

http://www.keppe.org/img/LuaR.png

Comment: It's not clear which part of the code you want to use a string.

Comment: The `<-LuaR` you see is the binary signature of precompiled Lua scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fixing it self with the Code

Source File (Contain)

```
void frmDevelop::on_actionBuild_Project_triggered()
{
    if (!isInLuaMode) return;
    const char* output = buildLua(cedit->document()->toPlainText());
    int length = strlen(output);
}
```

Header File (Contain)

```
private:
const char* buildLua(QString luaScript)
    {
        string ts = luaScript.toStdString();
        lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
        FILE* D = fopen("test.luac","wb");
        luaL_openlibs(L);
        luaL_loadstring(L,ts.c_str());
        lua_lock(L);
        int re = lua_dump(L,kpt_lua_Writer,D);
        lua_unlock(L);
        lua_close(L);
        fclose(D);
        return QString::number(re).toStdString().c_str();
    }

    static int kpt_lua_Writer(lua_State * /*l*/, const void *p, size_t sz, void *u)
    {
        return (fwrite(p,sz,1,(FILE*)u)!=1) && (sz!=0);
    }
```

test.luac must replace with your File Name :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the internals of Lua. In any case, you should call `luaL_loadstring` or `luaL_loadbuffer`, not `luaL_dostring`, which *executes* the code in the string:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_loadstring(L,s.c_str());
lua_dump(L,writer,NULL);
lua_close(L);
```

However, you should test the return values of both `luaL_loadstring` and `lua_dump`.

Comment: @hulkkiller, I don't know about C++ but your writer is fine C. Perhaps the compiler is complaining about it being static, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is cause by an invalid function prototype where `frmDevelop::writer` is implemented.

```
extern "C"
{
static int frmDevelop::writer(lua_State *L, const void *p, size_t size, void *u)
{
  // ...
}
}
```

You only *need* the `static` qualifier *at the point of declaration* in `class frmDevelop`. Also, `extern "C"` here isn't right since you're telling the compiler to not mangle the function name. But the compiler cannot honor that request because you're using a C++ feature(writer is part of `frmDevelop` and so you need the `::` scope operator) -- `extern "C"` just gets ignored for `frmDevelop::writer`.

Change writer's implementation from:

```
extern "C"
static int frmDevelop::writer(lua_State *L, const void *p, size_t size, void *u)
{ /* ... */ }
```

to

```
int frmDevelop::writer(lua_State *L, const void *p, size_t size, void *u)
{ /* ... */ }
```

and that'll fix the compile error you're getting.

Comment: cannot convert 'frmDevelop::writer' from type 'int (frmDevelop::)(lua_State*, const void*, size_t, void*) {aka int (frmDevelop::)(lua_State*, const void*, unsigned int, void*)}' to type 'lua_Writer {aka int (*)(lua_State*, const void*, unsigned int, void*)}' next problem

Comment: @hulkkiller make sure you're *not removing* `static` qualifier in the class frmDevelop definition for writer.